# Alterar um array de char dentro de uma função

Tags: c, array, return, char

Estou tentando passar um ponteiro de array char para uma função. Quero que a mesma faça alterações nesse array de char.

Segue o código da função:

```
void dhnfe( char tzd, char hverao, char *dh)
{
    if (hverao == 1)
    {

        switdh(tzd)
        {
        case -2: /*Fuso de Fernando de Noronha */
            dh = "%Y-%m-%d-T-%H:%M:%S-2:00";
            break;
        case -3: /*Fuso de Brasilia*/
        default:
            dh = "%Y-%m-%d-T-%H:%M:%S-3:00";
            break;
        case -4: /*Fuso de manaus*/
            dh = "%Y-%m-%d-T-%H:%M:%S-4:00";
            break;
        }
    }
    else if (hverao == 0)
    {
        switdh(tzd)
        {
        case -2: /*Fuso de Fernando de Noronha Horario de Verao*/
            dh = "%Y-%m-%d-T-%H:%M:%S-1:00";
            break;
        case -3: /*Fuso de Brasilia Horario de Verao*/
        default:
            dh = "%Y-%m-%d-T-%H:%M:%S-2:00";
            break;
        case -4: /*Fuso de Manaus Hoario de Verao*/
            dh = "%Y-%m-%d-T-%H:%M:%S-3:00";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Os tipos dos parâmetros não seriam `signed char` e `char`?

Comment: O que é `dhar`??

Comment: Na verdade era um erro de digitação, são "char"

Answer (score 0):

O que eu queria era alterar a string ***dh*** que passava como parâmetro na função. Na época eu passava como *dh ao invés de **dh/ *dh[].

Este código altera a string de duas formas diferentes (para fins didáticos), por retorno e dentro da função.

```
  static char  *dhnfe(signed char tzd,signed char hverao,char **dh){
char *aux;

if (hverao == 1){

    switch (tzd){
        case -2: /*Fuso de Fernando de Noronha */
            aux = "%Y-%m-%d-T-%H:%M:%S-2:00";
            break;
        case -3:/*Fuso de Brasilia*/
        default:        
            aux = "%Y-%m-%d-T-%H:%M:%S-3:00";
            break;
        case -4:/*Fuso de manaus*/
            aux = "%Y-%m-%d-T-%H:%M:%S-4:00";
            break;
    }
}else if(hverao == 0){
    switch (tzd){
        case -2:/*Fuso de Fernando de Noronha Horario de Verao*/
            aux = "%Y-%m-%d-T-%H:%M:%S-1:00";
            break;
        case -3:/*Fuso de Brasilia Horario de Verao*/
        default:        
            aux = "%Y-%m-%d-T-%H:%M:%S-2:00";
            break;
        case -4:/*Fuso de Manaus Hoario de Verao*/
            aux = "%Y-%m-%d-T-%H:%M:%S-3:00";
            break;
    }
}
*dh = aux;
return aux;
```

}